# How to configure Doctrine entities to handle compressed blobs in the database?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, entity, blob

I'm using Doctrine 2 as an ORM to the database and i'm having an issue with compressed blobs.

I'm storing text in a compressed blob column in the database. How can i specify this in the entity mapping xml config? I'm currently using `type="blob"` for this column but this isn't returning a string. I could use `type="text"` but this returns garbage as it's not uncompressing it.

Can i specify somewhere in my entity config that this text need uncompressing on retrieval and compressing on persisting?

Here's my entity configuration:

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="AccountNote" table="tblAccountNote">
        <id name="intAccountNoteId" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="intAccountId" type="integer" nullable="false" unique="no" />
        <field name="bolHiddenNote" type="boolean" nullable="false" unique="no" />
        <field name="binNote" type="blob" nullable="false" unique="no" />
        <field name="strHash" type="string" length="32" nullable="true" unique="no" />
        <field name="dtmCreated"   type="datetime" nullable="false" unique="no" />
        <field name="stmTimestamp" type="datetime" nullable="false" unique="no" />
        <many-to-one field="objAccount" target-entity="Account" inversed-by="objNotes">
            <join-column name="intAccountId" referenced-column-name="intAccountId" />
        </many-to-one>
    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end we decided on handling the compression in the getter and setter and removing it from the schema.